# CMD gives me the error "The system cannot find the file output.txt"

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch script that creates a file called "output.txt" and writes some system information. I want to open that file and store that information in a variable. however, when I run the script it gives me the "system cannot find the file output.txt". This is the same script that writes the file as well.

```
@echo off
(wmic os get Caption)>>output.txt
for /F "tokens=2* skip=1" %%G in (output.txt) do set info=%%G
echo version:%info%
pause
```

`(wmic os get Caption)>>output.txt` works becuase It creates a file with the following lines:

```
Caption                    
Microsoft Windows 10 Home
```

I'm simply trying to get the windows operating system name and store it in a variable for example

```
info=Windows 10 Home
```

Comment: `(wmic os get Caption|MORE)>output.txt` to de-unicode the `wmic` output. You probably want to assign to `%%H` not `%%G`. Note single `>` to create rather than append. OTT, works for me....!

Comment: Try typing `wmic /format /?` as CSV would be a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do it without creating an intermediate file to read then delete:

```bat
@For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%A In ('WMIc OS Get Caption /Format:MOF 2^>Nul')Do @Set "info=%%A"
```

You should have the value stored, *(without any unnecessary trailing characters)*, to the variable `%info%` for the duration of the `cmd.exe` session, as long as you don't modifiy/overwrite it.

```bat
Echo Version:%info%
```

*Please note that there is a bug in Windows 7, (I think), which may prevent the `mof.xsl` file from being picked up by `WMIC.exe`. There are both temporary and more permanent fixes or workarounds for that though, which are really outside of the scope of your question.*

**[Edit /]**

I thought I'd include this [registry](/questions/tagged/registry) based [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) as a quicker to retrieve alternative solution:

```bat
@For /F "EOL=HTokens=2*" %%A In (
    'Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /V ProductName 2^>Nul'
)Do @Set "info=%%B"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using a full path so output.txt can end up anywhere. Your example does work on my machine so maybe your real code is a little bit different?

Since you are already using `for /F` you might as well just parse the command directly without a temporary file:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A IN ('wmic os get Caption /value^|find "="') DO @set info=%%B
echo.info=%info%
```